# Spring Authorization Server 1.0.0: invalid_client error while requesting /oauth2/token

Tags: java, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-authorization-server

I have setup a simple Spring Authorization Server using the [example](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/tree/main/samples/default-authorizationserver) provided in the Spring Authorization Server repo.

I am using [OIDC Debugger](https://oidcdebugger.com/) to test it out. I am able to get the form login page. I enter my user ID and password, and I'm successfully able to get the Authorization code. The next step is to exchange this code to get the access token (from the `/oauth2/token` endpoint). Here is where I get an error.

This is my request to `/oauth2/token`

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
--data-urlencode 'client_id=messaging-client' \
--data-urlencode 'client_secret=secret' \
--data-urlencode 'code=ARfoO0m_srZSzi0RJgryvAyxOEmcoOHAZbFVYJlmng71x1CTv7qdCGD3I-DwG8EuBYBdyUGhmZwo5LBmoXyoxxuEuSZwJ7tPjYvQED7OBriRc4uFky5NbtNKuctz1PGt' \
--data-urlencode 'redirct_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foidcdebugger.com%2Fdebug'
```

When I send this request, I get a `401 Unauthorized` error with the body as follows:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

My Security Configuration (just showing the client setup for brevity)

```
@Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .clientId("messaging-client")
                .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/messaging-client-oidc")
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                .redirectUri("https://oidcdebugger.com/debug")
                .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                .scope(OidcScopes.PROFILE)
                .scope("message.read")
                .scope("message.write")
                .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(true).build())
                .build();

        // Save registered client in db as if in-memory
        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        registeredClientRepository.save(registeredClient);

        return registeredClientRepository;
    }
```

And, I am also using `1.0.0` version of the Spring Authorization Server dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing?

**Edit: ** I also tried to pass the client ID and secret as a Basic Auth Header (Base64 encoded), as follows:

```
  curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/token' \
    --header 'Authorization: Basic bWVzc2FnaW5nLWNsaWVudDpzZWNyZXQ=' \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
    --data-urlencode 'grant_type=authorization_code' \
    --data-urlencode 'code=ARfoO0m_srZSzi0RJgryvAyxOEmcoOHAZbFVYJlmng71x1CTv7qdCGD3I-DwG8EuBYBdyUGhmZwo5LBmoXyoxxuEuSZwJ7tPjYvQED7OBriRc4uFky5NbtNKuctz1PGt' \
--data-urlencode 'redirct_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foidcdebugger.com%2Fdebug'
```

But this time, I get a `400 Bad Request` error with the following payload

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Comment: Hi Sriram, you pointed out two options for the request toekn. What approach did you use at the end? I am having the same issue.

Comment: I used the first approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. In the request to /oauth/token, I had made a typo in the `redirect_uri` parameter. I fixed that, and it worked.

It was a silly mistake from my side!

Answer (score 0):

> I am using OIDC Debugger to test it out.

What is the `Authorize URI` that you give the debugger? You cannot use `localhost` there as it needs to be accessible to the debugger.

I suggest either setup port forwarding to the 8080 port or use tunneling/reverse proxy like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to temporarily expose your authorization server. Make sure to use the custom forwarding url instead of `localhost`.

Comment: I'm just using it to get the Authorization code. I feel the problem is in the /oauth2/token endpoint, which is returning invalid_grant.

Answer (score 0):

The example code you followed had this code

`

```
@Bean
    public EmbeddedDatabase embeddedDatabase() {
        // @formatter:off
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .generateUniqueName(true)
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
                .setScriptEncoding("UTF-8")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-schema.sql")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-consent-schema.sql")
                .addScript("org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/client/oauth2-registered-client-schema.sql")
                .build();
        // @formatter:on
    }
```

`

the addScript, where do I find the sql scripts? Because i tried to look for them in resources folder, but could not find them.

Comment: Got the scripts

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/main/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/resources/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/oauth2-authorization-schema.sql